# How to run a vba macro on a specific worksheet without leaving the current worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I would like to have a VBA code run on one, or more, specific worksheets of a workbook in Excel. But I do not wish to activate the worksheets where the code will run, I wish to have it done in the background and have the results shown on the current worksheet, where there will be a button do call the code.
All the responses I have seen to such question require visiting the worksheet where the macro will run but I would like to avoid that.
Perhaps putting the code inside a With statement will do the job? I have investigated it but cannot figure out all the dots in front of the lines.
I tried to post the code here but I keep getting indentation errors so I will omit it for now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be worth posting the code - even with indentation errors. Someone else will edit it if you're not able to do it to fix the indents etc.

Comment: you can turn off screenupdating and the macro will run in the background

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to access any worksheet and any cell in any worksheet in the workbook through VBA.

```
val = ActiveWorkbook.worksheets("Sheet2").cells(row, col).Value
```

Comment: How do you do it on multiple sheets at once?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
dim x as variant    
set x = sheets("Sheet1")
```

Just change the sheet name based on what you have.

Comment: You can also add application.screenupdating

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! I ended up activating every sheet (was in a hurry).
Best regards,